# Business dashboard for BPM engine(s)

Tags: workflow, visualization, dashboard, business-process-management, kpi

to select among BPM offerings, one of our key requirements is a business-level dashboard, which shows executive-level KPIs, such as process usage, delays, costs (based on costs of process steps), time spent, effectivity of human process particitpants, and the like.

My research so far has not resulted in an off-the-shelf dashboard - but maybe I missed an offering. Thus, two questions:

1. are there any off-the-shelf business-level dashboards on the market (either as plug-ins, or as fixed parts of existing BPM suites?)
2. are there any developer-level dashboards which can be "reduced" or configured to show only business-level details?
3. if such a dashboard must be custom-built, which BPM suites are bringing the max amount of needed functionality?
4. if such a dashboard must be custom-built, which frameworks/components/applications can and should be re-used instead of being written from the scratch?

Many thanks!

Michael

Comment: Just to clarify: "dashboard" means a **live** view of the BPM processes and the engine. So "dashboard" could also mean a cockpit, control center, etc.

Comment: To make this question easier to find, here is an incomplete, random list of potential candidates (as search query elements), in no special order: jBPM, Oracle BPM Suite, Software AG webMethods, Camunda Fox, IBM Business Process Manager, Bonita. For the dashboards, BIRT and Pentaho may be the keywords.

Comment: You can check out a product I've built to build Business Dashboards using PHP: http://razorflow.com . The advantage is that dashboards built with RazorFlow work great on mobiles and tablets as well, so your stakeholders can quickly see their KPIs on the go.

Answer (score 0):

The BonitaSoft Teamwork Edition had a gteat integration with BIRT Reporting

Answer (score 0):

Kontinuum Workflow / BPM Suite by Web and Flo has a built-in dashboard that might be able to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In IBM BPM 8.0 (and most recent) you can find two built-in dashboards, one is process performance dashboard that will indicate how many instances, average time of process , average time of tasks, bottle necks. And Team performance dashboard that will indicate over due tasks, etc.

A little late and just in case anybody is still searching